# Transparent proxy (including https) that authenticates to another proxy, in a NAT?

Tags: proxy, squid

We have a computer room in a NAT (using dnsmasq and arno iptables firewall). And this computer room is inside a University proxy, so all internet browsing must be authenticated. The topology is something like (sorry for my null ascii art)

Clients -> server eth1 (internal) -> server eth0 (external) -> University proxy with authentication -> Internet

Normally we instruct the students just to configure the proxy on their browsers and that is all. But lately we have been starting to use clients on the command line that also need to authenticate. For example, git push and pull, rstudio to download packages, emacs, etc. We have instructed students in this use case to simply export the variables https_proxy and related, and this works sometimes but no always and they keep forgetting the command line, or don't save it in .bashrc for later use, etc. In particular, emacs does not follow strictly those variables and we cannot easily install packages without authenticating again in emacs, etc.

So yesterday I was playing in a local client and found that by using a local proxy with squid that uses a cache_peer that forwards traffic to the actual university proxy ( and authenticates ) emacs worked without problem ( I just needed to setup the proxy in emacs, no auth needed). So I tried to replicate this for all students, installing squid on the server and trying to make it a transparent proxy , but it did not work. I kept getting ssl errors like bad hello msg and so on.

So, my question is: is it possible to setup a transparent proxy to forward all connections to the actual proxy (and authenticates using a single account, does not matter) to help the clients use connections on the console without having to configure the actual proxy? I don't want to mitm the ssl traffic, just to make it easier for students the command line browsing.

In the server I have squid3, arno iptables firewall with the transparent proxy plugin activated, and dnsmasq where the gateway client is configured to be the server. I am not knowledgeable on iptables, but I try to learn. I tried many examples on the internet but never got it working. Maybe is not possible because interception conflicts with authentication or something like that ...

My current squid config is the following (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787087/use-elpa-emacs-behind-a-proxy-requiring-authentication):

```
# Allow all for now
acl all src all
http_access allow all
icp_access allow all

never_direct allow all

# logs
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid

# turn off proxy-headers (no idea what is it :))
via off
forwarded_for off

# describe external proxy server
cache_peer <proxy_ip> parent <proxy_port> 0 no-query default proxy-only login=<my_login>:<my_password>
http_port 10000 transparent
acl port10000 myport 10000
cache_peer_access <proxy_ip> allow port10000
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: a direct TLS/SSL connections uses directly a... TLS/SSL protocol. Only when using a proxy, is the HTTP CONNECT command issued. A client will never issue such a command when it doesn't know there's a proxy hidden around. So the proxy has to talk TLS/SSL itself. Then that's the classical problem of trusting a certificate presented by the man-in-the-middle proxy with the name of the visited site: requires installing a Root CA on the client. Since all this was to avoid trouble when using various commands (curl, from some docker container...) you instead inherit new troubles

Comment: Ok, thank you, so basically it is not possible and not worth since I am a beginner in all this and I do not want to get more admin troubles just for this.